# Remove the column used for index with pd.MultiIndex.from_product

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe like so

```
dfDictionary = {'Results':['Home',
                                'Away',
                                'For',
                                'Against'
                                ],
                     'info':[ '-', '-','-','-',],
                     'rating':[ '-', '-','-','-',],
                     'review':[ '-', '-','-','-',]}
dfTable1 = pd.DataFrame(dfDictionary)
```

It looks like below

```
Results     info    rating  review
0   Home    -   -   -
1   Away    -   -   -
2   For     -   -   -
3   Against     -   -   -
```

I created a MultiIndex dataframe from this df like so `dfTable1.index =pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'Summary1'], dfTable1.Results])`

Now the dataframe looks like below. As you can see, the `Results` column is in both Index & column. I do not want the column anymore since it is in index, How do I do that with `dropping`? I ask "without `dropping`" because I do not want 2 levels in the column.

```
Results     info    rating  review
    Results                 
Summary1    Home    Home    -   -   -
Away    Away    -   -   -
For     For     -   -   -
Against     Against     -   -   -
```

I have another df almost exactly same

```
dfTable2 = pd.DataFrame(dfDictionary)
dfTable2.index =pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'Summary2'], dfTable1.Results])
```

And eventually I want to concatenate them with `resultsTable = pd.concat([dfTable1, dfTable2], axis = 0)`
Right now I get a dataframe like the pic below

[image]

What I want to achieve in the end is a df like below with a `header` column & I would do that with `resultsTable.columns =pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'Final Consolidated Table'], resultsTable.columns])`. But before that I need to sort the issue I have currently.

[image]

**Update**

With the initial solution provided by @jezrael, I was able to get the df like below after concatenating the 2 dataframes.

[image: ```]

Is there any way to get a dataframe like below? Basically I am trying to recreate a pandas df similar to the excel table. If this is possible, it would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with convert `Results` to index by dictonary for first level `Summary1`:

```
dfTable1 = pd.DataFrame(dfDictionary)

dfTable1 = pd.concat({'Summary1':dfTable1.set_index('Results')})
print (dfTable1)
                 info rating review
         Results                   
Summary1 Home       -      -      -
         Away       -      -      -
         For        -      -      -
         Against    -      -      -
```

Your solution working with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for use and drop `Results`:

```
dfTable1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'Summary1'], dfTable1.pop('Results')])

print (dfTable1)
                 info rating review
         Results                   
Summary1 Home       -      -      -
         Away       -      -      -
         For        -      -      -
         Against    -      -      -
```

Working like removed by `drop`:

```
dfTable1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[f'Summary1'], dfTable1.Results])
dfTable1 = dfTable1.drop('Results', axis=1)
print (dfTable1)
                 info rating review
         Results                   
Summary1 Home       -      -      -
         Away       -      -      -
         For        -      -      -
         Against    -      -      -
```

EDIT:

```
dfDictionary = {'Results':['Home',
                                'Away',
                                'For',
                                'Against'
                                ],
                     'info':[ '-', '-','-','-',],
                     'rating':[ '-', '-','-','-',],
                     'review':[ '-', '-','-','-',]}
dfTable1 = pd.DataFrame(dfDictionary)
dfTable2 = pd.DataFrame(dfDictionary)
    

dfTable1 = pd.concat({'Summary1':dfTable1.set_index('Results')})
dfTable2 = pd.concat({'Summary2':dfTable2.set_index('Results')})

resultsTable = pd.concat([dfTable1, dfTable2])
```

For expected ouput is necessary create helper DataFrame from columns names, for merged cells for `Results` is created 3 levels `MultiIndex`.

Then is separately written first header and and data without columns names:

```
d = {'level_0':'Results'}
header = resultsTable.reset_index().columns.to_frame().rename(index=d).replace({0:d})
header = pd.concat({'Final Consolidated Table':header.set_index(0, append=True)}).T.rename_axis([None, None, None], axis=1)

resultsTable = resultsTable.rename_axis([None, None])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    header.to_excel(writer, startcol=-1)
    resultsTable.to_excel(writer, startrow=2, header=None)
```